# Inject dependencies (like jQuery) into library when running Grunt

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm building a Javascript library using Yeoman and would like to load some dependency scripts when running Grunt.  For example, I want to use jQuery code in my tests, however when I do that now the testing suite tells me that **$ is not defined**.

I've included jQuery in the package's devDependencies.  How do I continue from there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use jQuery in your test (i guess you are using karma) you have to include jquery in your k`aram.conf.js` file. For example:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'app/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
      .....
    ],
....
```

Comment: so it's specific to the testing suite? im using qunit but have been thinking about switching to mocha.

Comment: Ah! Sorry i don't know quint. But it is also possible that they are also using a specific configuration file.

Comment: I am also having issues with $ not defined and I would like to use Jquery in my custom grunt task. Is the specific task's Gruntfile.js the appropriate place to inject JQuery? If so, what would the syntax look like to accomplish this?